# Sort each string inside list - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort each string inside a list. For example, if I have the list `['bca', 'fed']` then I want my function to return `['abc', 'def']`.

Currently trying to do this like so:

```
lines = [''.join.(sorted(e)) for e in lines]
```

What's wrong with this syntax?

Comment: `join.(sorted(e))` should just be `join(sorted(e))`

Comment: When you tried to run it, it gave you the reason why it wasn't running!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the redundant dot (`.`):

```
lines = [''.join(sorted(e)) for e in lines]
```